# Is it Join and except the best way for taking rows in priority dataFrame?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark 1.6.0 in scala, normaly I am using dataFrame for processing the data.
In this case and I need to create a dataFrame with these source dfEu,dfFlow and dfLt. 
The relationship between those are, dfEu with dfFlow, dfEu with dfLt
The logic that need to implement is the next.

1. Take all rows that join between dfFlow and dfEu
2. Take all rows that have dfFlow and I haven`t taken in below join
3. Take all rows tha have dfEu  and I haven`t taken in below join
4. Take all rows that have dfLt and I haven`t taken in dfEu

What is the best way to implement these?

Use dataframe join and Except?

Use a strutucture data key value, and implement the insert low priority to high (for keep the high priority).

Or are you advice me another strategy for that?

Best regards, and thank you for your time.